# Sorting and swapping tuples/tuple values in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

I have a list of tuples in Python and I would like to sort them based on the second value of the tuple (which is a string so I would like to sort them in alphabetical order) and swap the first values of the tuples. For example let's say that we have some list:

```
lst = [(1, "z"), (2, "a"), (3, "b")]
```

I would like the final result to be like this:

```
result = [(1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "z")]
```

Is this possible to do with a built in method or I have to write my own function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the list into two with the old `zip(*lst)` transpose trick, then sort the 2nd list and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) them back together:

```
lst = [(1, "z"), (2, "a"), (3, "b")]

lst1, lst2 = zip(*lst)
result = list(zip(lst1, sorted(lst2)))

# lst1: (1, 2, 3)
# lst2: ('z', 'a', 'b')
# result: [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'z')]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip`:

```
lst = [(1, "z"), (2, "a"), (3, "b")]
sort_l = [(a, c) for [a,_ ], c in zip(lst, sorted(b for _, b in lst))]
```

Output:

```
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'z')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a functional solution:

```
from operator import itemgetter

lst = [(1, "z"), (2, "a"), (3, "b")]

res = list(zip(map(itemgetter(0), lst), sorted(map(itemgetter(1), lst))))

print(res)

[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'z')]
```

Note you should not named variables after built-ins: use `lst` instead of `list`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not one line but if you want you can try:

```
lst = [(1, "z"), (2, "a"), (3, "b")]

first=[]
second=[]

for i,j in lst:
    first.append(i)
    second.append(j)

print(list(zip(sorted(second),first)))
```